# How to Open Pdf url without webview in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.3

Please tell me anyone who know how to open pdf url without webview in android or who know a best practice or library about it

example of pdf url=http://www3.nd.edu/~cpoellab/teaching/cse40816/android_tutorial.pdf

Comment: Download the PDF, then use [any of these PDF viewing solutions](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html).

Comment: do you know how to path our download to a directory asset of application?

Comment: Assets are read-only. Assets are in a directory on your development machine, but they are just entries in the APK on the device.

Comment: If you want to show it in your app you can use this https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Answer (score 0):

There are to methods :

***Force download and open it :***

```
 webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String aUrl, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

            fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(aUrl, contentDisposition, mimetype); //returns a string of the name of the file THE IMPORTANT PART

                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(aUrl));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                    String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(aUrl);
                    request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
                    request.setMimeType("application/pdf");
                    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                    registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));





        }


    });
```

and don't forget to add those methods to open pdf after download :

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            openFile(fileName);        }
    };

    protected void openFile(String fileName) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + File.separator +
                fileName);
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        try {
            this.startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
```

Also don't forget declaring perrmission in the :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

or you can only

***open it in intent***  :

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Both solutions are tested and works .

Comment: how I can save download file in my folder application maybe like folder asset?

Comment: you can save it out of the application and get it with external storage access

Comment: I want to save it in of the application, you have a suggetion code? or example application?